# Using Ember Data with Fixtures and returning a single object

Tags: ember.js

I have the following code:

```
App.UserAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    activity: DS.hasMany('activity'),
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    lastname: DS.attr('string'),
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    phone: DS.attr('string')                    
});
```

And a fixture:

```
App.User.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstname: 'John',
        lastname: 'Doe',
        username: 'jdoe',
        email: 'jdoe@apple.com',
        phone: '408-111-1111'
    }
];

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user');
   }
});
```

Now I want to access this data in a template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  {{#each}}
    <ul>
    <li>User: {{firstname}} {{lastname}}</li>    
    <li>User Name: {{username}}</li>
    <li>Password: {{input}}</li>
    </ul>
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

And its forcing me to access it as an array. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `DS.Store#find` and don't pass an id, it's going to return all of the records of that type.

If you want to find a specific record in the store you need to pass the id of that record.

For example, to find the user with the id of 1:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("user", { path: '/users/:id' });
});

App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', params.id);
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find

Comment: The problem with that "solution" is that it assumes I will know the id at design time, which I do not. I want this route to dynamically display the correct organization is response to a {{#link-to}}.      <td>{{#link-to 'contact' contact}} {{contact.firstname}} {{contact.lastname}} {{/link-to}} of {{#link-to 'organization' contact.organization}} {{organization.name}} {{/link-to}}</td>
        <td>{{input type="checkbox" name="completed" checked=completed}}</td>

Comment: You should take some time to read through the [Ember.js Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/), specifically the section about [dynamic routes](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments).

Comment: Yes I should re-read them. I am trying to do something tricky here and that is what makes it difficult for me. I want that user object available at all levels of the application. Maybe I should map it into the application controller or something?

Comment: At design time? isn't params.id dynamic, determined at runtime? What I did was first just query and get an array. Then, call `.find()` or `.findBy()` on THAT resulting array. (So you may call `.find()` twice, but once is on store, and the other is on an enumerable.